# Is there any device that can act as a iBeacon and allows writing to one of its GATT characterics?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I would like to detect a beacon and then write a value to some of its GATT characterictics, so other BLE-devices can read it. Is this possible at all? Or some special device is needed for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with a standard iBeacon because it is a transmit only device.

You might be able to build your own custom device to do this, but making it work on iOS when more than one Bluetooth device is around will be almost impossible.  This is because there is no way to correlate detected iBeacon identifiers with as connectable Bluetooth device -- iOS has sandboxed the CoreLocation iBeacon detection APIs and the CoreBluetooth APIs needed to read and write GATT characteristics.

As a result, you can never know for sure if you are writing to the same device you detected.

For a detailed explanation of the sandboxing of the CoreBluetooth and CoreLocation iBeacon APIs, see [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html).

Comment: But what about beacon's UUID? It can both be sent in iBeacon packet and be a readable GATT characteristic. Is that possible? Another thing, these guys https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/200868188-How-do-I-modify-UUID-major-and-minor-values- allow UUID/minor/major update, so it could possibly cover my case...

Comment: Don't confuse an iBeacon ProximityUUID with a Gatt Service UUID.  The two look the same, but they have completely different values.  Yes, beacon providers are able to use Bluetooth Gatt functionality to update the identifiers of the iBeacons.  But this is completely separate with reading these identifiers with CoreLocation iBeacon APIs.  Essentially, you can do what you want if you stick entirely with CoreBluetooth APIs and ignore the CoreLocation iBeacon APIs.  But then all apps using your custom bluetooth beacons will have to access them with CoreBluetooth not CoreLocation.

Comment: So if I had a custom device, which is set up (some magic here) to use exactly the same UUID for both ProximityUUID and for some GATT Service UUID, I would be able to discover it with CoreLocation and then update some characteristic of GATT service with CoreBluetooth, right? (And as UUID is the same, I would be sure proximityUUID and GATT Service UUID correspond to the same physical device)

Comment: This might work.  Just be careful never to have two of these dual advertisement devices with the same ProximityUUID within radio range, or you will not know which device you are connecting to.